# Spring MVC Simple Project - 404

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, libraries

I new about Spring, i'm trying to create a simple project but i can't figure it out!

I have java JDK 7 up to date.

Apache Tomcat 7 up to date.

Spring 3 framework / Eclipse JUNO 4 integrated.

[HERE](http://emanuelepirro.altervista.org/Java_EE_-_SpringMVCsrccontrollerHomeController.png)
it is my project structure (sorry for the external link bur i have not 10 reputation points)

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <!-- @Controller, @Service, @Configuration, etc. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My HomeController.java file:

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("HomeController: Passing through...");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

My problem is that when i call the servlet from the browser (for instance in that way):

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/home
```

**i have a HTTP 400 error - description The requested resource is not available.**

I suspect is a libraries problem but i put all the Spring libraries (and much more) in WEB-INF/lib. In the Eclipse project obviously i add everything in the classpath.

I paste the Tomcat's localhost log:

*

```
apr 13, 2013 3:44:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
apr 13, 2013 3:44:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@189b904')
```

*

and the Tomcat strERR log:

*

```
2013-04-13 15:44:46 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;;.
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 397 ms
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.39
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\.metadata
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\docs
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\examples
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\host-manager
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\manager
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\Servers
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\SpringMVC
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
apr 13, 2013 3:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 540 ms
```

*

I'm EXHAUSTED, i'm since yesterday to fight with this project, please help me! :)

Comment: I'm also starting with Spring. But I hope this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm) also help you. I used that link in creating my starting project.

Comment: What URL are you hitting? e.g http://localhost:8080/????

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: you set up looks correct, that is the correct xml file to use. Are you sure tomcat is on 8080 ?

Comment: yes 8080. when i call localhost:8080 start the default Tomcat page

Comment: might be worth specify "method = RequestMethod.GET" in th erequets mapping, although I am sure that is the default. I think that error comes from the jsp not being availbale, not the request mapping failing. Is the project being built and deployed correctly - the jsp is deployed where it should be within tomcat/webapps

Comment: In Tomcat the Java classpath is setted at: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" - It's regular?

Comment: the app is deployed succesfully, turn up your logging level, deploy in debug mode, check messages, make usr eyou are doing a hard refresh (ctrl+f5) in browser

Comment: I have no idea... it looks ok, post a link to projec ton github ? I stopped using eclispe for these exact reasons, intellij is much more helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much anyway Nim!

Comment: can you try adding an index.jsp  in WebContent folder (containing a redirect to home.jsp) eg:<% response.sendRedirect("home.jsp"); %>. I think the first page should be outside the controller.

Answer (score 0):

This might probably cause due to lack of needed libraries.Following is a list of libraries which spring includes in it's template project(library versions might differ).

[image: default library list in SpringMVC template project]

When moving forward you might experience that copying libraries is painful and there must be a better way to do this.

I have prepared a [blog post](http://anuruddhapremalal.blogspot.com/2013/02/hello-world-spring-mvc-application.html) on ,how to easily setup a springMVC project with the help of spring toolsuit plugin for eclipse.Hope it will be a very helpful reference for you.

Answer (score 0):

What is actually in "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\SpringMVC" directory? Does it have webapp directory structure?

It seems that Tomcat does not detect your appServlet(org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) according to stdErr log.

If you deploy your SpringMVC app correctly, you should see the following messages in the log file:

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
...
...
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 725 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

9 times out of 10, when I see the 404 error with Spring MVC, its usually because I fat-fingered the view name/path returned by my Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code structure everything looks perfect. 

Still if I were you, I would check the System.out.println() value to see whether the controller is really invoked or not and then I will make sure the location of home.jsp is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the request mapping of controller method to :

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "home")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("HomeController: Passing through...");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Remove `/` from `/home`.

Also your `web.xml` does not seem to have context listener.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name><param-value>     
        /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-security.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/hibernate-config.xml         
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- you seem to be missing this -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```